# How to get a band-limited digital modulation of X type?

Tags: modulation, digital-modulation

I am developing a program which should create modulated signals and combine them to  get an RF signal with different modulations on different frequencies with non-interfering bandwidths.

The problem is I am not able to find the equations which show the correlations between the bandwidth of the base-band signal and their configurations (samples per symbol, symbol rate, modulation type, pulse shaping filter, etc.).

The only two equations that I could find were for QAM/PSK and FSK.

> \$ FSK= \delta f +2*B\$.
>   \$QAM/PSK= (1+R)*B\$
>
> \$\delta f=\$ The distance between the two farthest frequencies used in FSK.
>   \$B=\$ The baud rate of the signal.
>   \$R=\$ The parameter of the raised root pulse shaping filter.

So my question is what are the equations to calculate the bandwidths of modulations that use MSK,PAM,ASK,CPM? Also doesn't root raised cosine also affect FSK bandwidth, shouldn't the B parameter be included in FSK's equation?

P.S.
I just learned about digital-signals and signal-processing in general in the last two weeks, so I do not have a proper grasp on some core concepts. I do have a bit of an intuitive understanding about how they work (e.g. I do know what FFT does but the math behind it is a bit murky for me). Please go easy on me. :)

Comment: FFTs are just correlations (That is, multiply and accumulate) that offer energy-peaking at exact integer multiples of 1 / time-window. To combine arbitrary waveforms with **LOW** crosstalk (intermodulation), you'll need low-distortion active circuitry.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf thanks for answering, I am not currently designing the circuitry, I am instead simulating the process of waveform generation and combination in LabVIEW programming environment.